# Does LibGit2Sharp ensures that the data being cloned from the Repository is the same as what we receive on our end?

Tags: c#, git, libgit2, libgit2sharp, data-integrity

I am working on an application that uses LibGit2Sharp to clone the data from Git Repositories. I want to know that whether LibGit2Sharp does any data integrity checks like SHA-1 after the clone is finished(successful or not) to ensure that no data is missing or is tampered.

Answer (score 0):

That is not a functionality of the libgt2sharp langauge bindings, but the underlaying libgit2.

Now, in fact, it's the business of the transport involved.

As far as I can tell, no, they don't do that. Feel free to browse their source code (https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/cc5966b071b37c38736ce8ad526e612d0703b523/src/transports/smart_protocol.c) like I did.

Comment: Actually I tried to compare the Git clones provided by the libgit2sharp and git bash. The Number of files and the folders are not the same(Obviously the size on disk too).

I went through this link that you sent me.I saw that they are checking for the packets sent and the received packets but they are not doing any SHA checks, are they?

Answer (score 0):

Git uses packfiles to transfer the objects between repositories. Each object in these packfiles has a CRC32 checksum and the packfiles themselves have a SHA-1 checksum trailer.

Both of these checksums are checked against the data that is received. This includes calculating the name of objects based on the data that was received rather than trusting the remote with the hashing.

But this is not about libgit2sharp or libgit2. This is how the Git system works. You can find information about the data format in its technical documentation.